# Javascript Eclipse Indentation problem with Object property

Tags: javascript, eclipse, indentation

Ok, I have a problem with eclipse/javascript. The identation inside of an object property is 8 spaces and it pisses me off. I want it to be 4 spaces. What do I need to change in order to fix that? I want eclipse to format it like "b".

```
var a = {
        t: 'Hi'
};

var b = {
    t: 'Hi'
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Eclipse Indigo (for J2EE)

> Window -> Preferences -> JavaScript -> Code Style -> Formatter

then Edit...

> Line Wrapping -> Expressions -> Object initializers -> Indentation policy: Indent by one

[image: screenshot for configuration]

Comment: Whoever decided to control the indentation from "Line Wrapping" instead of "Indentation" should be sent back to UX school.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem (also for Array).

The only thing that works for me is to disable the Smart Insert Mode (CTRL + Shift + Insert) to indent the first property, then if you enable it again it should be working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to check your Javascript formatter.

Go to Window->Preferences and type "Formatter" in the search box. From there you can modify the code style for specific languages.

Comment: Do you have a JavaScript plugin installed in Eclipse? If not, I don't think you will get formatting options.

Comment: What if you search for JavaScript under Window->Preferences? Do you have anything regarding formatting/code style?

Comment: Nope. It might be a bug because it seems like it's supposed to be 4. I'm using Indigo, btw.